# How to make new comment show up without refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I'm trying to add comments to my site using the acts_as_commentable_with_threading gem. I'm following this guide

http://twocentstudios.com/blog/2012/11/15/simple-ajax-comments-with-rails/

And the comments seem to be working fine, however, when I add a new comment I need to refresh the page for the comment to show up. When I delete the comment however, it goes away without having to refresh the page. This is what I have in the coffee file for the create and delete actions. (This is taken from the guide that I linked to above)

comments.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
      # Create a comment
      $(".comment-form")
        .on "ajax:beforeSend", (evt, xhr, settings) ->
          $(this).find('textarea')
            .addClass('uneditable-input')
            .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        .on "ajax:success", (evt, data, status, xhr) ->
          $(this).find('textarea')
            .removeClass('uneditable-input')
            .removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled')
            .val('');
          $(xhr.responseText).hide().insertAfter($(this)).show('slow')

      # Delete a comment
      $(document)
        .on "ajax:beforeSend", ".comment", ->
          $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5)
        .on "ajax:success", ".comment", ->
          $(this).hide('fast')
        .on "ajax:error", ".comment", ->
          $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1)
```

Is the functionality of making the comments automatically appear without refreshing the page not handled by this code? Thanks

**EDIT:** It seems as though the ajax request isn't successful when creating the comment because when I change it to ajax:complete, it then semi-works. The text area is re-enabled but the comment still doesn't show up. How do I see why the ajax request is failing?

Comment: try the .append() of jquery http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Doesn't insert after do that?

Comment: .insertAfter() in the last line of the creating a comment jquery

Comment: if you are brave you can take a look at action_cable I just build a demo chat https://github.com/mzaragoza/action_cable_chat I hope that this can help as guidance

Comment: Lol thanks ill take a look

Comment: perhaps deleting works as expected because you are binding the .on with a ".comment" and for the creating your using $(".comment-form") instead. Try using .comment (to show and hide) when creating.